# Wordpress featured image outside of loop

Tags: wordpress

I want to display the featured image outside of the WP-loop. e. g. like a background image of the body that is different in every post. I looked for two hours on google, but could not find a single piece of code that gives me an idea. But I suppose it is not that much complicated.

Has anybody here an idea how the retrieve the URL of the featured image outside the loop?

thank"

Comment: This question is off topic. Please include what you've tried as far as code is concerned.

Comment: Related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22013/post-thumbnail-outside-the-loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my preferred way:

```
<?php
$page = get_page_by_title('Title Here'); 
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $page->ID ), 'full' );
?>

<div class="background" style="background-image:url('<?php echo $image[0]; ?>');"/>
```

Comment: I nearly had it like that, but didi not know that you have to choose which item of the array you want to use. [0] What else is stored in that array?

Comment: I've done that so many times myself! the rest of the array is just image size info:) Happy coding, @rabo

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<?php
  global $post;
  if (has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)) {
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'single-post-thumbnail');
  }
?>
```

To get the url use:

```
<body style="background-image:url('<?php echo $image[0]; ?>');">
```